# stack implementation in C++ using template

Tags: c++, templates

In below program how can I print stack data in the member function of that class?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class box{
    public :
            vector<T> elems;
            void push(T); // pushing data into stack
            void pop();
            void display(); // displaying the stack data
};

template <class T> void box<T> :: push(T ele)
{
    elems.push_back(ele); // pushing stack elements
}

template <class T> void box<T> :: pop(void)
{
    elems.pop_back();
}

template <class T> void box<T> :: display(box &b)
{
  //How to display the data inserted in stack here??
}

int main(void)
{
    box<int> b;
    b.push(3);  // inserting stack data into template
    b.push(4);
    b.push(5);
    b.push(6);
    b.push(7);
}
```

I tried to print the data but it was not proper, so I am not sure how can I access the stack elements

Comment: "I tried to print the data but it was not proper" Please show what you tried and how it was not proper.

Comment: Access the elements by iterating over the `elems` vector.

Comment: pop should return a T: `T pop()`...

Answer (score 2):

No need to pass a `box& b`. You can do:

```
template <class T> void box<T>::display() {
    for(T& e : elems) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the "elems" vector and print its elements.

```
> template <class T> void box<T>::display() {
>     for(int i=0;i<elems.size();i++) 
>         cout<<elems[i]<<"\n";
> }
```

**NOTE:**
size() – Returns the number of elements in the vector.